# Python Round with different decimal automatic deciamal

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, decimal, rounding

i want to round the number showing in my table

it looks now like:

[image]

i want it looks like:

[image]

How can i get that? use pandas or numpy and as simple as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` , we can use `pandas.DataFrame.round`. See example below ( from pandas documentation )

data frame : **df**

```
    dogs  cats
0  0.21  0.32
1  0.01  0.67
2  0.66  0.03
3  0.21  0.18
```

Do round on **df** like below

```
df.round(1)
```

**Output:**

```
    dogs  cats
0   0.2   0.3
1   0.0   0.7
2   0.7   0.0
3   0.2   0.2
```

We can even specify the fields need to round, see link for more details : [pandas.DataFrame.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)

Or We can use default python round in a loop, as below

```
>>> round(5.76543, 2)
5.77
```